# Use of the phrase "so that"

Tags: meaning, idioms

In my current understanding, after the phrase "so that" should be the purpose of the action/incident preceding to "so that". For example:

> Darwinism must die so that evolution may live.

However I came across the following sentence in which "so that" is used to connect an action and the direction of the action.

> To obtain sufficient reflected light, install so that there are no obstacles in the optical path.

Is this use of the "so that" phrase also correct and common?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the same use as the first example you have. "Install" is being linked to "there are no obstacles in the optical path." That there are no obstacles would be the purpose of install.